# How to create a service that listens on the lock screen android java?

Tags: java, android

is there a way to code a Service that listens on Window Events in the lock screen, I would like to do detect a windowchangedfocus when the power off dialog shows up because lock the screen will lose focus to it and then I can override the OnWindowFocusChange method to lock the device again with DevicePolicyManager. I am doing this because the intent `ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS` got deprecated in Android 12. Here is some of the service class code I am trying to develop

```
public class ShutdownService : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            //below code will run when the service is created
            

        }
          //is there a way to override OnWindoFocusChanged here
    }
```

Any help even in Java to write a service class that will let me listen on these events could really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Broadcast Receiver

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

and

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your contribution but this is not working